# How discord store token?

Tags: javascript, discord, local-storage

Recently discord updated his app and web version. in this version, you are unable to find user tokens in localStorage and anywhere else.
an interesting fact is, if you delete all localStorage items, cookies and etc, you will still be logged in the discord!
my question is, how this is possible?! is there a new modern way of data storage on the client-side?
how does discord generate and login users from NOTHING?

Answer (score 4):

The token(s) should appear under the Storage tab under the values 'token' and 'tokens' of inspect element but for some reason, these values are only visible when the Responsive Design Mode is toggled:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlR78.png)

Comment: how is that possible?! even if you delete shown token in responsive mode, you will still be logged in!

Comment: @JohnJ if you delete the 'token' and 'tokens' local storage values, you will be logged out after you refresh the page, since your token is stored in both of them